# How to clean tuple and insert them in a csv file?

Tags: python, regex, csv

I'm printing out from a db to a csv file like this:

```
result = cursor.fetchall()
writer = csv.writer(writeFile, dialect='myDialect')
   for x in result:
      x = list(x)
      for z in x:
         z = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]',' ',z)
      x = tuple(x)
      writer.writerow(x)
```

I want to clean each string in my tuples removing punctuations. I've found this regex which is working well.

However it's not working as my csv file is still full of punctuations.

Comment: That replaces `z` but `x` remains untouched. You don't need inner loop and need to replace `x`, if I'm not wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iteration variable `z` holds just a copy of each value in `x`, so changes made to `z` are not reflected in `x`. You should use `enumerate` to iterate through `x` so that you can modify items in `x` via an index:

```
for i, z in enumerate(x):
    x[i] = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]',' ',z)
```